# If $f(f(x))$ is a linear function, must $f(x)$ be linear?

Tags: functions

I'm thinking of $f$ as a function either from the reals to the reals or from the naturals to the naturals.

Edit: Okay, what if $f$ is from the naturals to the naturals?

Comment: $f=\frac{1}{x}$

Comment: The question from the naturals to the naturals is much more interesting.

Comment: Are there any where $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut Take $f(x) = -x$ for $x < 0$ and $f(x) = 0$ for $x \ge 0$

Comment: @TrevorGunn That's a nice example; thanks.

Comment: @W.mu Another one of those is $f(x)=\frac{x}{Cx-1}$ for any real $C$.

Comment: @AlexanderBurstein If you take $f(f(x))=x$, then $f(x)=f^{-1}(x)$, which means the figure $y=f(x)$ is symmetric about the line $y=x$, and these functions are infinite.

Comment: @W.mu Right, but I was thinking about rational functions with that property, like $C/x$ or $C-x$. In fact, the example I gave is the conjugate of $C-x$ by $1/x$.

Answer (score 5):

Another family of examples for $\mathbb N$: 
Let $p$ be prime, $q$ coprime to $p$.  $f(n) = p n$ if the $p$-adic order of $n$ is even (i.e. $n = p^e m$ where $e$ is even and $m$ is coprime to $p$), otherwise $f(n) = q n/p$.  Then $f(f(x)) = q x$.

Comment: Great answer! +1

Answer (score 4):

If you want one from the naturals to the naturals, take $f(x)$ to be the function $f(1)=2,f(2)=1$, and $f(n)=n$ for $n\geq 3.$

Comment: Both examples exploit the fact that the identity is linear, but I wonder if these can be adapted to a case when, say, $f(f(x))=2x$. My intuition says the answer is no on the naturals.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri That would be interesting. I agree with your intuition but I don't see a quick reason why it'd be impossible, especially when you can define $f$ to be some nasty piecewise defined thing

Comment: @Fimpellizieri [Here's a question similar to yours](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1265139/253966). It gives a solution to $f(f(x))=2x$ on the naturals.

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut Very interesting! Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

No. For example,$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
\displaystyle \frac{1}{x}; & x \neq 0\\
0; & x = 0
\end{cases}.
$$

Answer (score 3):

As for $\Bbb N$, let $f(n)=n+1$ for odd and $=n-1$ for even $n$. One can twist this to fancier constructions by fancier partitions of $\Bbb N$.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't directly answer the question, but if $f$ is continuous from $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, it still can be nonlinear. For a concrete example, see the comments on [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1964698/253966) to one of my previous questions in a similar vein to this one; essentially, one can rotate the graph of

$$y=\epsilon \cos(x)$$

for small enough $\epsilon$ exactly $45^{\circ}$ counterclockwise, and it satisfies the property.